# implementation of queue using stack with REVERSE

Tags: data-structures, stacks

> Suppose a stack implementation supports an instruction REVERSE, which reverses the order of elements on the stack, in addition to the PUSH and POP instructions.

---

I'm looking for implementation of queue where ENQUEUE takes a sequence of three instructions and DEQUEUE takes a single instruction , or any better algorithm .

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? What's your *question*? This is not a place to outsource your work.

Comment: I got , ENQUEUE : reverse , push , reverse  and DEQUEUE : pop !

Comment: That's some code, but what are your thoughts? Have you tried your idea on some examples? Have you tried to prove it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queue should append items to the rear of the stack, and get them off the top, so here's a pseudocode implementation of your two functions:

$\texttt{Queue::Enqueue}(e):$
$\quad$Reverse;
$\quad$Push($e$);
$\quad$Reverse;

$\texttt{Queue::Dequeue}():$
$\quad$__return__ Pop;

Verify for yourself whether and why these functions produce the desired behaviour: why does the $\texttt{Enqueue}$ function reverse the stack, but not $\texttt{Dequeue}$?